# Рекурсивный поиск узла в ассоциативном массиве

Tags: php, рекурсия

В ассоциативном массиве произвольной вложенности необходимо отыскать и вернуть элемент по ключу и все его дочерние элементы. (Ключами элементов являются ID-записи из БД - так проще для всех манипуляций):

```
Array
([1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => главная
        [parent_id] => 0
        [is_visible] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [title] => новости
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [is_visible] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [6] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 6
                                        [title] => запись 6
                                        [parent_id] => 4
                                        [is_visible] => 1
                                    )

                                [7] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 7
                                        [title] => потомок 4го поколения
                                        [parent_id] => 4
                                        [is_visible] => 1
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [9] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 9
                                                        [title] => потомок 7 
                                                        [parent_id] => 7
                                                        [is_visible] => 1
                                                    )

                                                [10] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 10
                                                        [title] => потомок 7-2
                                                        [parent_id] => 7
                                                        [is_visible] => 1
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [8] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 8
                                        [title] => потомок 4го пок 2
                                        [parent_id] => 4
                                        [is_visible] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => архив
        [parent_id] => 0
        [is_visible] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [title] => запись5
        [parent_id] => 0
        [is_visible] => 1
    )
```

)

Написанный мною код выполняет эту функцию, однако при нахождении заданного узла, **не получается выйти из рекурсии**. Т. е. элемент определяется, но код продолжает работать, пока не переберет все элементы до конца массива. Я уже методом тыка вставлял и return, и break - ничего не выходит. Подскажите, как после нахождения узла возвратить результат с выходом из рекурсии (и из цикла вообще).

Код:

```
public static function find_node($dataset,$id){
        // $dataset-массив, $id-требуемый ключ узла
        global $result; // иначе $result будет undefined
        foreach ($dataset as $key=>$value){
            echo "$key,";// здесь вывожу $id, чтобы следить за работой кода
            if ($key != $id){
                if (isset($dataset[$key]['children'])) {
                     self::find_node($dataset[$key]['children'], $id);
                } 
            } else {
                $result = $dataset[$key];
                // return нельзя - происходит возврат на следующую итерацию
            }       
        } 
        return $result;
}
```

UPDATE!!!
Задал вопрос и тут же догадался сам - добавил строку, все работает.

```
 public static function find_node($dataset,$id){
        global $result; // иначе $result будет undefined
        foreach ($dataset as $key=>$value){
            echo "$key,";
            if ($key != $id){
                if (isset($dataset[$key]['children'])) {
                     self::find_node($dataset[$key]['children'], $id);
                } 
            } else {
                $result = $dataset[$key];
            }       
            if ($result) return $result; // вот он - выход!
        } 
        return $result;
}
```

Может быть есть более лучшие предложения?

Comment: ну так надо если вы нашли, то почему бы не вернуть это сразу? т.е. не `$result = $dataset[$key];`, а `return $dataset[$key];`

Comment: @ BOPOH, обновил вопрос - нашел сам ответ. По поводу вашего комментария - пробовал, не работает.

Comment: 1) ваш и мой вариант ничем по сути не отличаются, только у вас рекурсия не правильная (хотя бы из-за необходимости `global $result;`), поэтому для моего коммента надо было и рекурсию нормально сделать 2) можно немного улучшить: перед самим поиском делать проверку `isset($dataset[$id])` и если найдено, то сразу его возвращать 3) сейчас некогда, вечером если не забуду (или если никто больше не напишет нормальный ответ) - покажу как надо было делать рекурсию

Comment: @BOPOH  Да там править то еще одну строчку и все. Вызов делать сразу с присваиванием `$result=self::find_node($dataset[$key]['children'], $id);`  И все, слово global можно (и нужно) убирать

Comment: @BOPOH, "сразу его возвращать" не получается, если элемент найден в иерархии, то return возвращает управление из текущей итерации на уровень выше, а полного выхода из цикла не происходит. Буду рад, если получится избавиться от global!

Comment: @Deus И разумеется оставить вашу проверку, которую вы добавили

Comment: @Deus, вам Mike выше показал как надо было сделать, так рекурсии и пишутся. Кроме того - что мешает проверять наличие ключа до цикла? Вы себе кучу времени так сократите

Comment: BOPOH и MIKE, ни один из ваших советов почему-то не работает.

Comment: @Deus А вы к своему конечному варианту это добавляете ?

Comment: @Mike, конечно. $result все равно не определен. Я улучшил код - изменил строку $result="" - теперь работает без global

Comment: @Deus Теперь вам надо, как советует BOPOH, первой строкой функции написать `if(isset($dataset[$id])) return $dataset[$id];` и внутри foreach можно выбрасывать if($key!=$id) и блок else.

Comment: @Mike, может все-таки запостите нормальный ответ? судя по всему человек не совсем разобрался с рекурсией, поэтому не понимает что и как надо сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function find_node(&$dataset,$id) {
   if(isset($dataset[$id])) return $dataset[$id];
   foreach ($dataset as $value){
      if (isset($value['children'])) {
         $result=self::find_node($value['children'], $id);
         if ($result) return $result; // вот он - выход!
      }
   }
  return false;
}
```

Сократил код и добавил `&` у параметра, что бы массив передавался по ссылке, что значительно быстрее.

Comment: Красота! Спасибо за ответ. С детства боюсь рекурсии. Пишу рекурсивные функции методом проб и ошибок!

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_search_recursive($var,$arr=[]){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
        $GLOBALS['keys'][][$key] = $item;
        if($key === $var){ return $GLOBALS['keys']; }
        if(is_array($item)){ return array_search_recursive($var,$item); }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: $GLOBALS must die